# CLion add dependency headers and sources

Tags: c++, makefile, clion

I have a project that uses C in some modules and C++ in others - everything being built with a `Makefile`.
I created a `CMakeLists.txt` file that just calls the `Makefile` so the project can be imported in Clion. When I run my program, I get a segfault in one of the libraries I previously built (so, I have the sources, the headers and the static library) - so I'm trying to debug that library in the context of my project.

Now, my question is how do I add the headers, library and library sources to my project in Clion so I can set breakpoints and debug it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your library to the sources with a separate CMake like:

```
set(HEADER_FILES ...)
set(SOURCE_FILES ...)
add_library(<lib_name> STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

Then you link you program with a library in CMake like that:

```
target_link_libraries(<prog_name> <lib_name>)
```